# ASIHTTPRequest not connecting using proxy parameters in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, proxy, asihttprequest

The error code I'm receiving:

> Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x6993280 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6d520c0 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 306.)"

I do not have option but ASIHTTPRequest. I have already developed the app and cannot use the any alternatives.

Currently we are using iOS version 5.1.1

I have developed the app one year back with the same code for iOS 3 and it was working properly. Now same code is failed to work. I suspect this happens with the latest iOS versions.

This code works well without proxy settings but not with proxy settings.

```
_method = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"http://%@%@", _settings.ServerLocation, _settings.WebServicePath];
NSLog(_method);

NSString *soapMessage = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n",
                         parameters,
                         @"</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"];
//NSLog(@"soapMessage : %@",soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURLURLWithString:_method];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequestrequestWithURL:url];

if(_settings.IsProxy)
{
    [request setProxyHost:_settings.HostIP];
    [request setProxyPort:(NSInteger)_settings.Port];
}   

constchar *utfString = [soapMessage UTF8String];
NSMutableData *req = [NSDatadataWithBytes:utfString length:strlen(utfString)]; 

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length"value:[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]]]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction"value:action]; 
if(_settings.IsProxy) 
{
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Host"value:_settings.HostIP]; 
}

[request setPostLength:[soapMessage length]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setPostBody:req];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:5];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:1];

if(_settings.IsProxy)
{
    if([_settings.Usernamelength] > 0) 
    {
        [request setProxyUsername:_settings.Username];
    }

    if([_settings.Passwordlength] > 0) 
    {
        [request setProxyPassword:_settings.Password];
    }

}

//[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: its much more likely that you are connecting to a different proxy with a different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the [ASIHTTPRequest Libraries](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and it worked as i expected.

before it works, i have removed below line of code

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Host"value:_settings.HostIP];
```